# Creating new column from subset of values of another column, matching certain criteria

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I don't know the terminology, but I need to take the values associated with the controls of my treatment column into a new column where the control values are associated with the same position and gene name. The control values will be repeated for each treatment but that's ok. The goal is to simplify some z-score operations in the future.

This is what I have:

```
GENE    TREATMENT   POSITION  VALUE
gene1   treatmenta  1         112
gene1   treatmenta  2         134
gene1   treatmentb  1         124
gene1   treatmentb  2         115
gene1   control     1         205
gene1   control     2         223
gene2   treatmenta  1         123
gene2   treatmenta  2         149
gene2   treatmentb  1         132
gene2   treatmentb  2         116
gene2   control     1         258
gene2   control     2         235
```

And this is what I want:

```
GENE    TREATMENT   POSITION  VALUE  CTRL_VALUE
gene1   treatmenta  1         112    205
gene1   treatmenta  2         134    223
gene1   treatmentb  1         124    205
gene1   treatmentb  2         115    223
gene2   treatmenta  1         123    258
gene2   treatmenta  2         149    235
gene2   treatmentb  1         132    258
gene2   treatmentb  2         116    235
```

I tried fiddling with dplyr's inner_join and left_join but the values weren't matching. How do I wrangle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We group by 'GENE', 'POSITION', create the new column 'CTRL_VALUE' by based on the logical expression constructed around TREATMENT column, get the corresponding 'VALUE' and later `filter` out the rows where 'TREATMENT' is 'control'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(GENE, POSITION) %>% 
     mutate(CTRL_VALUE = VALUE[TREATMENT == "control"]) %>% 
     ungroup %>%
     filter(TREATMENT != 'control')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  GENE  TREATMENT  POSITION VALUE CTRL_VALUE
  <chr> <chr>         <int> <int>      <int>
1 gene1 treatmenta        1   112        205
2 gene1 treatmenta        2   134        223
3 gene1 treatmentb        1   124        205
4 gene1 treatmentb        2   115        223
5 gene2 treatmenta        1   123        258
6 gene2 treatmenta        2   149        235
7 gene2 treatmentb        1   132        258
8 gene2 treatmentb        2   116        235
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GENE = c("gene1", "gene1", "gene1", "gene1", "gene1", 
"gene1", "gene2", "gene2", "gene2", "gene2", "gene2", "gene2"
), TREATMENT = c("treatmenta", "treatmenta", "treatmentb", "treatmentb", 
"control", "control", "treatmenta", "treatmenta", "treatmentb", 
"treatmentb", "control", "control"), POSITION = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), VALUE = c(112L, 134L, 124L, 
115L, 205L, 223L, 123L, 149L, 132L, 116L, 258L, 235L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```